# how to sum the value, python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, sum

I have some code :

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'sentencess' : sentencess,
    'publishedAts' : publishedAts,
    'hasil_sentimens' : hasil_sentimens
})
df.to_csv('chart.csv')
df['publishedAts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['publishedAts'], errors='coerce')
by_day_sentiment = df.groupby([
        pd.Grouper(key='publishedAts',freq='D'),
        'hasil_sentimens'
    ]).size().unstack('hasil_sentimens')
sentiment_dict = by_day_sentiment.to_dict('dict')
sentiment_dict_new = {
    k: {
        m.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'): v if v == v else 0 for m, v in v.items()
    } for k, v in sentiment_dict.items()}
filter = {k:list(v.values()) for k, v in sentiment_dict_new.items()}
```

The output from filter is:

```
{
    'Negatif ': [4.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0],
    'Netral ': [3.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0],
    'Positif ': [0, 0, 1.0, 1.0],
    'tanggal': [
        '2019-08-27 00:00:00',
        '2019-08-28 00:00:00',
        '2019-08-29 00:00:00',
        '2019-08-30 00:00:00'
    ]
}
```

How to sum value from key, So, I expect the output to be:

```
{'Negatif ': [10.0], 'Netral ': [9.0], 'Positif ': [2.0]}
```

Comment: and what do you intend to do with the key  `tanggal` ?

Comment: let it same, I mean `{'Negatif ': [10.0], 'Netral ': [9.0], 'Positif ': [2.0],'tanggal': [
        '2019-08-27 00:00:00',
        '2019-08-28 00:00:00',
        '2019-08-29 00:00:00',
        '2019-08-30 00:00:00'
    ]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
filter = {k:sum(list(v.values())) for k, v in sentiment_dict_new.items() if k!= 'tanggal'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
>>> {k: [sum(v)] for k,v in filter.items() if type(v[0])!=str}
{'Negatif ': [10.0], 'Netral ': [8.0], 'Positif ': [2.0]}
```